# Ion-select with dynamic options in Ionic 2?

Tags: angular, ionic2, ionic2-select

I'm developing application in Ionic 2. I need to add ion-select options in dynamic way, but I'm stumped on something that is probably very simple. Here is my code snippet.

```
<ion-select [(ngModel)]="classifications" (ngModelChange)="updateSelectedValue($event)">
 <ion-option *ngFor="#key of classifications" value="key" [checked]="true">{{key}}</ion-option>
```

```
this.classifications = this.local.get('classifications')._result;
    console.log('classifications: '+ this.local.get('classifications')._result);


updateSelectedValue(event:string):void {
   this.selectedObject = JSON.parse(event);
   console.log('selectedObject: '+this.selectedObject);
}
```

Output for console log:

```
classifications: ["Any","Agriculture, Forestry, And Fishing","Mining","Construction","Manufacturing","Transportation, Communications, Electric, Gas, And Sanitary Services","Wholesale Trade","Retail Trade","Finance, Insurance, And Real Estate","Services","Public Administration "]
```

I'm getting exception as well.

```
EXCEPTION: Cannot find a differ supporting object '["Any","Agriculture, Forestry, And Fishing","Mining","Construction","Manufacturing","Transportation, Communications, Electric, Gas, And Sanitary Services","Wholesale Trade","Retail Trade","Finance, Insurance, And Real Estate","Services","Public Administration "]' in [classifications in JobsearchPage@30:17]
```

**Edit:**

And its not setting its value to select options. I have done this in Angular 1.

```
<select id="classificationId"  data-role="listview" data-inset="true" ng-options="classification as classification for classification in classifications " ng-model="classification" x-ng-change="update(classification)">
<option value=''>Classifications</option></select><select id="classificationId" data-role="listview" data-inset="true" ng-options="classification as classification for classification in classifications " ng-model="classification" x-ng-change="update(classification)"><option value=''>Classifications</option></select>
```

**Edit (from comment to an answer)**

```
export class JobsearchPage { 
    selectedClassification:string; 
    constructor(http: Http, 
        nav: NavController, 
        messagesService:MessagesService, navParams:NavParams) { 
      this.http = http;
      this.messagesService = messagesService; 
      this.nav = nav; 
      this.classifications = new Array("t9it", 'uitut');
      console.log('STP selected'+selectedClassification); 
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't use Ionic but I'm pretty sure `ngModel` should point to a field that holds (or gets assigned to) the selected option not the entire list of possible options

```
<ion-select [(ngModel)]="selectedClassification" (ngModelChange)="updateSelectedValue($event)">
 <ion-option *ngFor="#key of classifications" value="key" [checked]="true">{{key}}</ion-option>
```

```
class MyComponent {
  selectedClassification:string;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Gunter, Im getting EXCEPTION: ReferenceError: selectedClassification is not defined. and selected value not assigning to select option component.
export class JobsearchPage {
selectedClassification:string;
 constructor(http: Http, nav: NavController, messagesService:MessagesService, navParams:NavParams) {
 this.http = http;
        this.messagesService = messagesService;
        this.nav = nav;
        this.classifications = new Array("t9it", 'uitut');
        console.log('STP selected'+selectedClassification);
}

Comment: Sounds like the HTML is not in the view of the same component otherwise it would find `selectedClassification`

Answer (score 1):

You can try (ionChange)='func($event)' and func(event){console.log(event);}

Answer (score 0):

Same as @Gunter said me too not familiar with ionic but yes may be your problem with `ngModel` which is always points to single field which is assigned to it. not the whole Object/Array/whatever.

Upto my understanding you want to get selected option which is you created dynamically so there are two methods you have either you have set `[(ngModel)]` to single string like this.

```
<ion-select [(ngModel)]="selectedvalue" (ngModelChange)="updateSelectedValue($event)">
 <ion-option *ngFor="#key of classifications" [value]="key" [checked]="true">{{key}}</ion-option>
```

or second method is apply a change event to the select option like this.

```
<ion-select #newSelect (change)="selectedvalue = newSelect.value">
 <ion-option *ngFor="#key of classifications" [value]="key" [checked]="true">{{key}}</ion-option>
```

here is my case `selectedvalue` is your key's value which option you have selected.

Comment: Your second option seems to work for me, but it gives below error.ReferenceError: selectedvalue is not defined, although I defined it in my class. selectedvalue;console.log('selectedvalue: '+ selectedvalue);

Comment: i assumed `selectedvalue` as key of ngModel. and also try to initialize first as `selectedvalue:string = null` may it works for you.

Comment: After setting selectedvalue:string = null; its returns as undefined. constructor(http: Http, nav: NavController, messagesService:MessagesService, navParams:NavParams) {
 this.http = http;
        this.messagesService = messagesService;
        this.nav = nav;
        this.selectedvalue:string = null;
        this.classifications = new Array("t9it", 'uitut');
 }

Comment: in the edited post there is no `selectedvalue` defined.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me :

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-label>Select Name</ion-label>
    <ion-select type="text">
        <ion-option *ngFor="#userInfo of userInfos"  value="{{userInfo.id}}">{{userInfo.name}}</ion-option> 
    </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

For some reason. not sure why but it still works even if you do not state a  `[(ngModel)]`

Answer (score 0):

## Class: today-input.ts

export class TodayInputPage {

```
public _projectName: string;
public projectDetails: any;
```

}

## HTML: today-input.html

```
     <ion-item no-lines>
      <ion-label>Project Name</ion-label>
      <ion-select type="text" [(ngModel)]="_projectName">
        <ion-option *ngFor="let p of projectDetails" value="{{p.projectName}}">
          {{p.projectName}}
        </ion-option>
      </ion-select>
    </ion-item>
```

---

Where **projectDetails** values comes from service.

## projectDetails object

### { date:"03/04/2017", duration:"07:30", projectName:"XYZ" },...

**_projectName** in your class will hold selected value.